# Для чего статическая переменная в качестве возвращаемого значения?

Tags: php

Для чего в этом методе значение возвращается как статическая переменная? Что это может дать или какие задачи решать ? почему нельзя просто `return array(...)`.

```
public static function getSystemParameters()
{
    static $params = array(
        "login",
        "login_form",
        "logout",
        "register",
    );
    return $params;
}
```

Comment: мб атавизм рефакторинга. мб нюансы выделения памяти

Comment: А в PHP массивы по ссылке или значению передаются? Если я этот массив поменяю, он везде где его из этой функции получили изменится?